# How to prevent resize initial column in c# winforn datagridview?

Tags: datagridview, resize, datagridviewcolumn

In my DataGridView, I have set

```
AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
```

And it works fine except for the very first column which I have marked with red arrow.  Where is the property that controls this column?

[Click to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNcXk.png)

Comment: That column is the RowHeader column that allows the user to select the whole row to delete etc... It is called RowHeader and there are several properties for this header. One is `RowHeadersVisible` to turn this column on or off depending on your needs.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of trying those series of RowHeaders..... properties.  Learning C#, and got a tunnel vision.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [RowHeadersWidthSizeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheaderswidthsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `DisableResizing`.

Comment: When @JohnG mentioned RowHeadersVisible property I saw other properties including RowHeadersWidthSizeMode as well, and made appropriate changes.  Thanks.